# Regular expression to mask credit card digits in a file

Tags: sed, regular-expression, replace

What is the most simplest way to mask all numbers but the last 4 digits of a credit card number in a file using sed.

Using egrep with the following regular expression we can find numbers of Visa, Mastercard, Discover, American Express, Diner's Club, and JCB.

```
egrep "(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|5[12345][0-9]{14}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[012345]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}|6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}|(?:2131|1800|35[0-9]{3})[0-9]{11})" transactions.log
```

Keep in mind that other essential numbers may be present in this transactions.log. This numbers should not be touched and are in other formats than credit card numbers

Example of credit card number format: `38012345678901`
Example of other numbers format: `2014-02-11 22:23, 1134-53553, 4-5-6-7-7-2`

Visa: `4123456789012`, `4123456789012345`, `41234567890123456`

MasterCard: `5123456789012345`, `512345678901234`, `51234567890123455`

Discover: `6011123456789012`, `6512345678901234`, `601112345678901`, `60111234567890123`

American Express: `341234567890123`, `371234567890123`, `34123456789012`, 301234567890123, 3712345678901234

Diner's Club: `37012345678901`

JCB: `213112345678901`, `180012345678901`, `3512345678901234`, `21311234567890`, `18001234567890`, ,`2131123456789012`, 
`1800123456789012`,
`35123456789012`

Easiest find and replace is?

Comment: NOTE: A credit card number would not be found at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 2):

To replace first 10 digits with `*` if, and only if, the number has exactly 14 digits:

```
sed 's/\([^0-9]\)[0-9]\{10\}\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([^0-9]\|$\)/\1**********\2\3/g'
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'foo bar 38012345678901 2014-02-11 22:23, 1134-53553, 4-5-6-7-7-2, 
  28012345678901,,,,, 3801234567890123456789 stuff' | \
  sed 's/\([^0-9]\)[0-9]\{10\}\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([^0-9]\|$\)/\1**********\2\3/g'

foo bar **********8901 2014-02-11 22:23, 1134-53553, 4-5-6-7-7-2,
  **********8901,,,,, 3801234567890123456789 stuff
```

---

**Edit**

To match exactly patterns from updated example:

```
sed 's/\([^0-9]\)4[0-9]\{8\}\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([^0-9]\|$\)/\1**********\2\3/g;s/\([^0-9]\)4[0-9]\{11\}\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([^0-9]\|$\)/\1**********\2\3/g;s/\([^0-9]\)4[0-9]\{12\}\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([^0-9]\|$\)/\1**********\2\3/g;s/\([^0-9]\)5[12345][0-9]\{10\}\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([^0-9]\|$\)/\1**********\2\3/g;s/\([^0-9]\)5[12345][0-9]\{9\}\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([^0-9]\|$\)/\1**********\2\3/g;s/\([^0-9]\)5[12345][0-9]\{11\}\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([^0-9]\|$\)/\1**********\2\3/g;s/\([^0-9]\)3[47][0-9]\{9\}\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([^0-9]\|$\)/\1**********\2\3/g;s/\([^0-9]\)30[12345][0-9]\{8\}\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([^0-9]\|$\)/\1**********\2\3/g;s/\([^0-9]\)3[47][0-9]\{10\}\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([^0-9]\|$\)/\1**********\2\3/g;s/\([^0-9]\)3[47][0-9]\{8\}\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([^0-9]\|$\)/\1**********\2\3/g;s/\([^0-9]\)6011[0-9]\{8\}\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([^0-9]\|$\)/\1**********\2\3/g;s/\([^0-9]\)6011[0-9]\{9\}\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([^0-9]\|$\)/\1**********\2\3/g;s/\([^0-9]\)6011[0-9]\{7\}\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([^0-9]\|$\)/\1**********\2\3/g;s/\([^0-9]\)65[0-9]\{10\}\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([^0-9]\|$\)/\1**********\2\3/g;s/\([^0-9]\)2131[0-9]\{6,8\}\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([^0-9]\|$\)/\1**********\2\3/g;s/\([^0-9]\)1800[0-9]\{6,8\}\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([^0-9]\|$\)/\1**********\2\3/g;s/\([^0-9]\)35[0-9]\{8,10\}\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([^0-9]\|$\)/\1**********\2\3/g'
```

This for the following file:

```
Example of credit card number format: 38012345678901 

Visa: 4123456789012, 4123456789012345, 41234567890123456

MasterCard: 5123456789012345, 512345678901234, 51234567890123455

Discover: 6011123456789012, 6512345678901234, 601112345678901, 60111234567890123

American Express: 341234567890123, 371234567890123, 34123456789012, 301234567890123, 3712345678901234

Diner's Club: 37012345678901

JCB: 213112345678901, 180012345678901, 3512345678901234, 21311234567890, 18001234567890, ,2131123456789012, 1800123456789012, 35123456789012

Example of other numbers format: 2014-02-11 22:23, 1134-53553, 4-5-6-7-7-2
```

gives

```
Example of credit card number format: 38012345678901 

Visa: **********9012, **********2345, **********3456

MasterCard: **********2345, **********1234, **********3455

Discover: **********9012, **********1234, **********8901, **********0123

American Express: **********0123, **********0123, **********9012, **********0123, **********1234

Diner's Club: **********8901

JCB: **********8901, **********8901, **********1234, **********7890, **********7890, ,**********9012, **********9012, **********9012

Example of other numbers format: 2014-02-11 22:23, 1134-53553, 4-5-6-7-7-2
```

Of course initial `38012345678901` doesn't match as it is not present in any of card pattern list.

Comment: Except that not all credit card numbers have the exact number of digits you are using in your example. Have you looked at the given regular expression at all?

Comment: If there are more formats (then in your example) you should list all of them in the question, nobody will be guessing what you are trying to do from some grep snippet.

Comment: I updated the answer, your grep patterns doesn't match examples which you gave, but whatever...